# on mac ,eclipse can't find device when my android project set "Project Build Target" highter than device'

Tags: android, device

i have install the eclipse with version 4.4.1,and then install the ADT with version 23.0.4.1468518 by eclipse help. then download the android sdks. now i can creat android application projects. but i found one bug,is:
 if i set one android project's "Project Build Target" is highter than my android device version(my android phone's android version is 4.0.3,but set project build target version 4.4.3),when i run the project ,it will not find my android phone; but if i set "Project Build Target"is 4.0.3 or even 2.2,my phone will be found ,and it can run well.
 this would not happened on windows,just mac.
what the matter with me,someone could help me?

Comment: If the `minSDKVersion` is higher than your phone or emulator, the device won't be found. `targetSDKVersion` is completely ininfluent: it normally should be set to the maximum available in your SDK arsenal.

Comment: i have set minSdkVersion=8 and targetSdkVersion=21.the same project can run in my 4.0.3 android iPhone on windows8.1 . but just the mac's eclipse can't find the same iPhone with same project.when the project set "Project Build Target" is 4.0.3 or 2.2 , it can find my iPhone,but project have much errors. it meams on windows,is ok,even 4.4.3,but on mac os,begin occure error.

Comment: `the same project can run in my 4.0.3 android iPhone on windows8.1` --- **my Android iPhone**?! are you **kidding** us? Now, I want to see the photos of your **Android iPhone**!! Really, `Apple is producing Android devices`?! **It's the end of the world**!! I'm going to suicide today... ;)

Comment: i have two computers,one is mac,other is a lenovo PC(windows8.1).they have install eclipse and ADT both.and i have a android phone,its system is android 4.0.3.   so i creat one android project,the project set "Project Build Target" 4.4.3 in eclipse. then i run the android project to my phone by my lenovo computer and mac. use lenovo ,android project can run well ,but use macbook it can't find my android phone.

Comment: but ,when i use the macbook run the project,it not always can't find my phone.if i set the project's "Project Build Target" 4.0.3 or 2.2, could run well in my phone.

Comment: it's OK,i did nothing;

Comment: I suicided 1 week ago - can't help you anymore... ;)